# Build Failed: Deployment.apps "<service_name>" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers: Required value

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm

I got this error after I added the `volumeMounts` and `volumes` into the deployment.yaml.

My deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "chart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "chart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "chart.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "chart.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      securityContext:
      {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      {{- if not .Values.developerMode }}
      volumes:
        - name: config-vol
          configMap:
            name: service-config
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
          {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ default .Chart.AppVersion .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:
          {{- range .Values.env }}
            - name: {{ .name }}
              value: {{ .value | quote }}
          {{- end }}
          ports:
            - containerPort: {{ .Values.container.port }}
          resources:
          {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          {{- if not .Values.developerMode }}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /src/config
              name: config-vol
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: {{ .Values.service.targetPort }}
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 15
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: {{ .Values.service.targetPort }}
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 15
            failureThreshold: 3
      {{- if not .Values.developerMode }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{ end }}
      {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

My ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config.json: |
    {{- toPrettyJson $.Values.serviceConfig | nindent 4 }}

kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: service-config
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

The build worked before I added the `volumes` and `volumesMounts` and I don't know why it failed as I think everything should be correct.

Comment: Helm's template looks good to me. 
Did you try to run a "helm install --dry-run --debug" to inspect generated yamls ?

Comment: If the Helm values don't have `developerMode` set to `true`, the chart won't emit most of its content.  Are you missing some `{{ end }}` statements, for example after the `volumes:` block?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the root cause. It's because there are two `{{ end }}` placed in the wrong position. The last two `{{ end }}` should place under the `securityContext` and `resources`